# How to enable "Contribution note" field while recording Contribution in the backend?

Tags: civicontribute, profile

"Contribution Note" field seems only available thru Profile. Although it looks like a civicrm core component. I did not create this using custom fields. How Can I enable it as part of other contribution related record.

[image]

Once used this field on Online contribution page, it appears in view contribution like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Erik, I have found it. Its the contribution.tpl
By removing "collapse" from the Additional/honoree/Premium block, it worked.

Before

```
<div class="crm-accordion-wrapper crm-ajax-accordion crm-{$paneValue.id}-accordion {if $paneValue.open neq 'true'}collapsed{/if}"
```

After

```
<div class="crm-accordion-wrapper crm-ajax-accordion crm-{$paneValue.id}-accordion {if $paneValue.open neq 'true'}{/if}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a default field already related with contribution

when creating a contribution just look for "Additional Details" profile where you can find "Notes" add a value to it you will get the same result

Also you can find the field values in the DB table called "civicrm_note"

Comment: Thanks. I just overlooked it!!
 Is there a way to uncollapse the tab additional details by default?

Comment: Not in the UI, you can change the css class? From

Comment: @Tapash looks like you should change the accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

If I want to change some values on a template I will create my own template like this:

```
<div id='expert-cases'>
  <div class='crm-summary-row expert-cases'>
    <div class='crm-label'>{ts}Main Activities{/ts}</div>
    <div class='crm-content'>{$countExpertCases}</div>
  </div>
</div>
{literal}
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    cj("#tagLink").parent().parent().prepend(cj("#expert-cases").html());
  </script>
{/literal}
```

in this example I add a field to the template and use jQuery to move it to the right spot. Yours is even simpler, you need to change the class. Adding the template to the form is then

```
CRM_Core_Region::instance('page-body')->add(array(
      'template' => 'CRM/Threepeas/Page/ExpertCases.tpl'));
```

in the right spot. In you case probably in the buildForm hook of the Contribution page.

Comment: Thanks, It will be useful in the future!! I have managed to get this worked out.

Comment: The advantage of doing it this way is that you are much less likely to be hurt by upgrades then when you change the template :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not uncollapse in the UI as far as I know. You can the css class?
Default will be

```
crm-accordion-wrapper crm-ajax-accordion crm-AdditionalDetail-accordion collapsed
```

If you leave out the 'collapsed' it is uncollapsed.

Comment: Thanks for that Erik. But Where do I put this code in?

Comment: You could put it in a small extension, in a template file and apply that to the form in question with CRM_Core_Region. But that sort of requires CiviCRM customization skills. You could check the documentation on creating extensions (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) and on Region (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Region+Reference). But that might well be more than you bargained for :-)

Comment: And check here http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in+Screens

Comment: I have custom tpl directory setup. Can I not include the line AdditionalDetails.tpl? would that work?

Comment: Yes, and then you change the class in your custom tpl.

Comment: `{if $isOnline}{assign var=valueStyle value=" class='view-value'"}{else}{assign var=valueStyle value=""}{/if}
<div id="id-additionalDetail" class="section-shown">
    <table class="form-layout-compressed">`
which part of this class should i replace with your code please?

Comment: No, you are looking at the wrong spot, let me check for you. Just a minute....

Comment: I can not see the code in the tpl file, see my new answer for a Region example